# Screen lock shuts down all applications

Tags: 17.10

I have Ubuntu 17.10. When I enable "Power Saving / Blank screen" and screen locks after N minutes, all running applications shut down. Is it normal? If no how can I fix it?

Comment: This is a bug with Ubuntu. It is being tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1458158). And has also been reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005418/13693) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023819/13693)

Answer (score 2):

You may be experiencing the problem described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023819/screen-lock-shuts-down-all-applications-in-17-10), which I asked in response to your question because your question had attracted comments that did not address the problem.

In my case, the problem was that the Wayland X server was crashing immediately after blanking the screen. The solution was to switch to the legacy Xorg server, by choosing "Ubuntu on Xorg" as the session type when logging in. You do this by clicking the gear icon next to the "Sign In" button on the login screen, after selecting your user from the user list.

Comment: I have installed Debian 9 instead Ubuntu and can't check this issue now but seems like you are right. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspend.html

> When you suspend the computer, you send it to sleep. All of your applications and documents remain open, but the screen and other parts of the computer switch off to save power. The computer is still switched on though, and it will still be using a small amount of power. You can wake it up by pressing a key or clicking the mouse. If that does not work, try pressing the power button.
>
> Some computers have problems with hardware support which mean that they [may not be able to suspend properly](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html). It is a good idea to test suspend on your computer to see if it does work before relying on it.

First check if it's acting the way it should.  The [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/?_ga=2.141028594.136816834.1516066718-1967148895.1516066718) is a great resource for that.

If there is a problem, start by looking at your logging to understand what's happening.  [`dmesg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/dmesg.1.html) makes it easy.  It grabs things from `/var/log` so you don't have to poke around as much.

```
user@hostname:~ $ dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

You can also use `grep` to look for log entries relating to power stuff.  This shows the format difference for syslog from grep.  dmesg is counting the time from startup, so 5.000000 would be five seconds after the kernel starts.

```
user@hsotname:~ $ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -iE "power|sleep|shutdown"
Jan 15 21:56:49 hostname systemd[11559]: Starting Shutdown.
Jan 15 21:56:49 hostname systemd[11559]: Reached target Shutdown.
```

---

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns

Comment: Suspend works fine, not a problem. But after screen goes blank i can see in logs: Jan 16 09:33:00 pc-ubuntu systemd[5453]: Reached target Shutdown. 
Jan 16 09:47:00 pc-ubuntu systemd[7494]: Reached target Shutdown. 
Jan 16 09:55:00 pc-ubuntu systemd[8422]: Reached target Shutdown.

Comment: "The screen goes blank," do you mean when the screen locks?  Try this to adjust the lock time: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-screenlocks.html.  Try this to adjust the blanking time: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-blank.html.  If you still need help please use explicit terminology to describe: 1. what you want to do and 2. what happens when it doesn't work.  Reference for power terminology: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html.

Comment: Sorry, I mean screen lock, but in settings it's named as "Blank screen". I want my applications continue running after screen locks. But instead all applications shut down when screen locks.

Comment: try removing the [automatic suspend](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-autosuspend.html) setting, or make it longer (maybe 8hrs).  "In the Suspend & Power Button section, click Automatic suspend."  So modify this setting.

Comment: I have turned it off. But it's not a good option.

Comment: that's the intention of the suspend; it's working the way it should be.  feel free to ask another question if you have another concern.  if this got you working though please mark as answered.

Comment: But suspend and screen lock is not the same. My concern is about screen lock, not about suspend.