# Why does Ubuntu 17.10 choose to close windows when it locks the screen?

Tags: lock-screen

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10. Sometimes, when I return to the PC and the screen is locked and I unlock it, all previously opened windows are gone. I truly don't understand the rational for this behavior.

I'd like to know how I can configure the system so that the windows are still present when I unlock the screen again.

**Edit**: it appears that I am running Gnome as window manager.

```
$ printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"
Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Session: ubuntu
```

Comment: That is not intended behavior. I think you have discovered a bug. Are you using Gnome, Unity, or some other Desktop Environment?

Comment: How do I determine whether I am using Gnome or Unity?

Comment: Here are [several ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running). Please edit your question to add the information - it simply makes a difference about which package you will file the bug report against.

Comment: Just the same here... I couldn't figure out why this is happening, since I reinstalled my OS last week and having this trouble sometimes when I lock screen.

Comment: This is a bug with Ubuntu. It is being tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1458158). And has also been reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023819/13693) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/996366/13693)